# How to Solve interface Errors

Tags: c#

i have four errors for interface and i can not understand these error here is my code. i mentions the area where i found error.
in error 1 i got this error "type 'ISAPI' in interface list is not an interface"
in error 2 i got this error "interfaces can not contain fields"
in error 3 i got this error "interface members can not have definitions"
in error 4 i got this error "interface members can not have defination"

```
enter code here

using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace InsertFromAndroidToSql

{
public interface SAPI : ISAPI // have error 1
{
    SqlConnection dbConnection; // have error 2
    void ServiceAPI() // have error 3
    {
        dbConnection = DBConnect.getConnection();
    }

    void CreateNewAccount( string Name, 
                           string userName, 
                           string password, 
                           string PhoneNumber, 
                           string CNIC) // have error 4
    {
        if (dbConnection.State.ToString()=="Closed")
        {
            dbConnection.Open();
        }
        string query = "Insert Into UserDetails VALUE ('" + Name + "','" + 
userName + "', '" + password + "', '" + PhoneNumber + "', '" + CNIC + "');";

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, dbConnection);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        dbConnection.Close();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: the errors seem quite clear, ISAPI isnt an interface, so dont declare this as one, the rest then may fall into place.

Comment: Please read up on what an interface is, SO is not the first place to go for this.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/

Comment: You might want to clarify what exactly you are having trouble with those error messages. I am happy to give you the benefit of the doubt that you are having trouble with them but you need to explain why - why do you think each of those four things should work or alternatively why have you had problem fixing them based on the messages you were given.

Comment: i am very new in C# and this is my first week in C# so i cant understand these errors. guide me through code

Answer (score 0):

Answering your question

> How to Solve interface Errors

- Error 1:

  - Your interface must derive from an interface. `ISAPI` is apparently not an interface.
- Error 2:

  - Interfaces cannot contain fields. Declare it as property with get and/or set.
- Error 3:

  - You cannot define method bodies in an interface. Only declare them.
- Error 4:

  - Same as 3.

*This would be a valid interface:*

```
public interface SAPI
{
    SqlConnection dbConnection { get; }
    void ServiceAPI();
    void CreateNewAccount(string Name, string userName, string password, string PhoneNumber, string CNIC);
}
```

Or declare your current 'interface' as **abstract class**.

```
public abstract class SAPI //...
```

Comment: i am solving first two error but can not understand last two. can you guide me through proper code

Comment: @FarrukhMughal Declare means only the method signature as you can see in my interface sample. You cannot define these methods in an interface though (means the body of the method in which the logic is).

Answer (score 0):

Do this first and look at error it will be reduce to 1 error

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Data.SqlClient;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Web;

 namespace InsertFromAndroidToSql
  {
   public interface SAPI : ISAPI // have error 1
 {
     //SqlConnection dbConnection; // have error 2   this is fields in 
     // interface you are declaring comment it or remove it 
     void ServiceAPI();    // have error 3   declare it dont define its 
    // functionality in interface
    //{
    // dbConnection = DBConnect.getConnection();
    //}

void CreateNewAccount( string Name, 
                       string userName, 
                       string password, 
                       string PhoneNumber, 
                       string CNIC); // have error 4  same remove its definition
  //{
  //  if (dbConnection.State.ToString()=="Closed")
  //  {
    //    dbConnection.Open();
  //  }
   // string query = "Insert Into UserDetails VALUE ('" + Name + "','" + 
  //userName + "', '" + password + "', '" + PhoneNumber + "', '" + CNIC + 
  //"');";

   // SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, dbConnection);
   // command.ExecuteNonQuery();
   // dbConnection.Close();
  }
 }
```

Once you will do it your code will be like

```
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Data.SqlClient;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Web;

 namespace InsertFromAndroidToSql
  {
     public interface SAPI : ISAPI // have error 1
      {  

         void ServiceAPI();       
         void CreateNewAccount( string Name, 
                   string userName, 
                   string password, 
                   string PhoneNumber, 
                   string CNIC);
  }
 }
```

now you got how the interface looks like check  **"ISAPI"** is an interface or not and if its not an interface you can inherit or extend it to current interface. Remove it or fix it to be an interface.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you are trying to define variables and methods on an interface, which is not allowed. Below I copied the explanation on classes and interfaces from Microsoft docs.

[Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/classes)

> A class is a construct that enables you to create your own custom types by grouping together variables of other types, methods and events. A class is like a blueprint. It defines the data and behavior of a type. [..] client code can use it by creating objects or instances which are assigned to a variable.

[Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/)

> An interface contains definitions for or a group of related functionalities that a class [..] can implement.

---

So what does this mean? In your example you have a reference to an interface or class, I'll assume for now its an interface. Lets say its defined as follows:

```
public interface ISAPI
{
    void CreateNewAccount( /* parameters omitted*/ );
}
```

The piece of code means that we condesider something to be an `ISAPI` if, and only if, they implement all of the defined functions (in this case, only `CreateNewAccount()`).

The define something as an `ISAPI` you need to create a Class that implements it, for instance:

```
public class Sapi : ISAPI {

     public void CreateNewAccount( /**/ ) {
          // Do something that creates an account.
     }
}
```

The `Sapi` class actually contains the implementation of the `ISAPI` interface.

---

I hope this clear things up a bit, I would strongly advise you to find a tutorial that fully explains how to use classes, abstract classes and interfaces and the differences between them.